# SQL Join 3 tables group sum

Tags: sql, join, sum

- Products  with Id-Prod , desc, date fields
- ENTRIES  with Id-Prod Quantity, Amount.
- Sorties  with Id-Prod Quantity, Amount.

I want to make a query which join the 3 tables on Id-Prod and grouping it and sum the quantity and Amount for each products them calculate the stock  which is equal to  sum quantityIn -Sum QUantityOut
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  If you want a fast answer (or any answer at all) you should tidy up your question so it is more clear.  You can include some sample data perhaps.

Comment: The question isn't too clear. Could you provide some sample data and the result you'd like to get for this sample?

Comment: There is no way to answer this because you don't tell us how to calculate quantity in and quantity out.

Comment: or maybe that is entries vs sorties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To join and sum with 1-N looks like this -- we need to do a sub query to get the sums before the left join and a coalesce to set nulls to 0.

```
SELECT P.ID-Prod,
       COALESCE(E.s,0) AS IN-Q,
       COALESCE(S.s,0) AS OUT-Q, 
       COALESCE(E.s,0) - COALESCE(S.s,0) AS Stock
FROM Products P
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID-Prod, SUM(Quantity) AS s 
           FROM ENTRIES GROUP BY ID-Prod) E ON P.ID-Prod = E.ID-Prod
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID-Prod, SUM(Quantity) AS s
           FROM Sorties GROUP BY ID-Prod) S ON P.ID-Prod = S.ID-Prod
GROUP BY P.ID-Prod
```

Comment: Without a tie between Entries and Sorties, couldn't the Entries and Sorties Quantity be artificially inflated by the joins?  thus perhaps the sums need to be accomplished before the join?  (I'll agree that the question is unclear as to this aspect however)  Imagine entry quantities of 1,2,3 for product 1. and sorty of 4,5 for product 1.  if quantity 1 ties to both 4 and 5; 1 will be counted twice, and 4 would be counted 3 times, once for each record in entry.

Comment: @xQbert you mean if there is 1-N in E and S table?  Yeah that's an issue... let me fix.

Comment: 1-N yes. the question is unclear to the details but it seems like a plausible risk given the table structure.

Comment: Thank you very much I got the following code  : SELECT Products.`ref`, Products.Products, 
(select sum(Entries.Packs)  from Entries where Entries.Products = Products.ref)  AS QuantiyIn,  
(select sum(Sorties.Packs) from Sorties where Sorties.Products = Products.ref ) AS QuantityOut 
FROM Products    it works  goods but now i need to get the stock i mean QuantityIn - QuantyOut  = Stock   how to do it I know It should very easy but i am newbie    thank you again

Comment: @YahiaBaiba - there is a reason I did it the way I did with the group by and the external join not the internal one... my is much faster -- please do it my way.

Comment: @YahiaBaiba - I added stock into my answer.

Comment: @Hogan Thank you very much   you are so great

Comment: @Hogan i am new here. I have 2 tables :"Order" and "order-details" as master and child table  order-details OrderId item Quantity , Price  Amount, SubTotal. now while adding new line to order details I want to calculate on fly the the subtotal  which is the SUM of Amount and insert it in SubTOtal field